# webpack order of css chunks

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I use webpack, with `ExtractTextPlugin`, so it creates CSS chunks for each JS chunk. the problem is that the order of the css files I import gets messed up.

For example, if I import css in my app bundle:

```
require("./a.css");
require("./b.css");
```

And then "CommonChunkPlugin" works on this code and takes the require of `b.css` to the vendor file it creates, then the `b.css` will be in the chunk of the vendor (e.g. `vendor.styles.css`) and `a.css` `b.css` will be in the main chunk.

How can I preserve the order of the CSS I am requiring?